# PDFMiner for extracting font size and face

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfminer

I am attempting to use PDFminer to extract PDF font information, but can't find the right documentation to perform this task. I looked at the README on Github, but was unsuccessful. I have the code working where it is converting the PDF to texts as expected. But if I want to take in a line of text and extract that font information how do I go about doing that?

Any help would be awesome!

I am using Python 3.6.3 with PDFMiner.six